# Issues with 'go build' on forked repository

Tags: go

I build a binary file for a GitHub repo (go code), which works fine. no issues.
I forked that repo, and modified a single line in the HTML file that has nothing to do with GO code, built the binary file for the new forked repo but the binary it generates refers to the original repo code, can't understand why.

I even cleaned all the code using `go clean -i all` command and manually removed all the installed code, binary files from $home/go/bin and the repo directory, but it still refers to the original repo code instead of new forked code.

---

Based on the solution suggested by Tobias, I performed the following steps:
[image]

After that, I executed `go build` in that repo directory, but the new binary file still refers to the old code. I even removed the old binary file and generated a new one.

[image]

Comment: Try to delete the binary again.
And do go install in your fork

Comment: @TobiasTheel, I did that already, multiple times, located all the binary files and deleted.

Comment: Okay, i don't exactly get your problem?
You want to use the installed binary of your fork, yes? 
If you deleted the old one and did a go install inside your fork, then everything should be fine

Comment: I really appreciate your help here. Yes, I want to use the installed binary of my fork. I am trying the steps you mentioned, yesterday it worked when I modified the Go files in the main directory but still not working when I modify the assets files (in another folder) which is what I have been trying from the beginning, must be my fault, because I don't much exp with Go Lang. But thank you for your help, will be using with the original repo for now due to time constraints.

Comment: Finally, this link helped: https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/181#issuecomment-65646229, the problem was not generic but repo specific.

Comment: Then i suggest, that you add the link + a short explanation as answer and accept your own answer :)

Comment: If you have actually solved the problem, you should either post your own answer or accept an existing answer. People will not expect to find answers in the question.

Comment: So it was XY-problem. I agree with @MichaelHampton that it would be better if you post your own solution as answer and accept it

Comment: Done. Apologies, I am new to Go Lang, but thank you all for your help. @TobiasTheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

At first I thought it was problem with a FORK (which is a common problem experienced with fork of Go language repo's), but it turns out, it was Repo specific problem. 
One of the dependent libraries had to be reinstalled for the forked repo to work, which was not mentioned in the Original repo docs.
Finally, this link helped: https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/181#issuecomment-65646229, the problem was not generic but repo specific
I followed the below steps from above link to resolve the dependency on go-bindata

```
go get github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/go-bindata
go build
```

Answer (score 6):

That's a common problem in go. The references system in "location based" so it searches for these files in the "correct" path. Idk if go modules fix this issue, but atleast when not using go modules you'll have to work around it.

You can solve it by

### Solution 1

1. Download the original repository you forked by:

> go get http://github.com/awesome-org/tool

2. Add your fork as remote

> git remote add awesome-you-fork http://github.com/awesome-you/tool

3. You'll have to make changes in the folder of the original downloaded repo and Push and Pull to/from your fork.

> git pull --rebase awesome-you-fork
>
> git push awesome-you-fork

### Solution 2

Work around go get:
You create the path the original repo would have, but clone your own fork into it. That way you can push & pull to your fork. That may be the better solution

```
cd $GOPATH
mkdir -p {src,bin,pkg}
mkdir -p src/github.com/awesome-org/
cd src/github.com/awesome-org/

git clone git@github.com:awesome-you/tool.git # OR: git clone https://github.com/awesome-you/tool.git
cd tool/
go get ./...
```

These Solutions were found here: http://code.openark.org/blog/development/forking-golang-repositories-on-github-and-managing-the-import-path

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but both the solution did not work for me.

Comment: But they should work. Over the time i'm using go i have successfully used both. 
Can you edit your Question and provide what you have tried exactly?
Maybe we can spot the mistake

Comment: I just used the second solution, worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 3):

The problem with a forked copy of a go packages is when the package is really multiple go packages in one repo, the import statements refer to original base repo, ie: `github.com/orig/repo`.

This is not an issue for repos with only one go package as it never refers to itself.

But if it has multiple, ie: package `github.com/orig/repo/A` imports `github.com/orig/repo/B`

And then you fork it as: `github.com/fork/repo`

Then when the go compiler sees `import "github.com/orig/repo/B"` in the source, it goes to download the original version and not your fork.

Fortunately, [go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) solves this.

Basically, create a `go.mod` at the top of your forked repo and add:
`module github.com/orig/repo`

then, the go compiler will assume that you are "orig/repo" regardless of where you actually are checked out from.

so, when `orig/repo/A` imports `orig/repo/B`, it will look locally.

If there are other imports you need to override that are outside the main forked repo, you can also force dependencies to come from another place using [replace](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive)

Comment: Thanks, let me try those steps and update you by tomorrow.

Comment: Maybe a GO111MODULE=on is needed here

Comment: Yes, GO111MODULE=on, or just put your code outside of GOPATH (which is what I do)

Comment: Btw. this should be the accepted answer, as using go modules is better than a workaround :)

Comment: I must share that I am new to Go language, but I did tried adding go.mod file, that didn't work, because the original repo does import other repo's but not in the format of `orig/repo/A`